# Joint probability distribution and normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I'm new to the subject of Joint probability distribution.

Let $X$ be a normal distribution variable with $\mu=10, \sigma^2=9$, and let $Y$ be a normal distribution variable with $\mu=5, \sigma^2=4$.
$X$ and $Y$ are independent.

We also set $T=2x, S=X-3Y$.

I need to compute $P${$S+T>0$}.

I know how to handle the simple case of $P${$X>0$} when $X$ is a normal distribution variable but I don't know what to do with $P${$S+T>0$}.

I think I need to use this theorem in my book: If $X_i$ is a normal distribution variable with $\mu_i, \sigma^2_i$ then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ has a normal distribution with $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mu_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sigma^2_i$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S+T = 3(X-Y)$

The distribution of $W = c(X-Y)$ where $X$ follows $\mathcal{N}(\mu_X, \sigma^2_X)$ and $Y$ follows $\mathcal{N}(\mu_Y, \sigma^2_Y)$ is, $\mathcal{N}(c(\mu_X-\mu_Y), c^2(\sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y))$. Then $P(W>0) = 1-\Phi_W(0)$.

Deriving the distribution of $W$,

$$M_{W}(t) = E(e^{tW}) = E(e^{ct(X-Y)}) = E(e^{ctX})E(e^{-ctY}) = M_X(ct)M_Y(-ct)$$

Use the mgf of $X$ and $Y$ to derive the expression of $M_{W}(t)$ and relate the resulting expression with the general expression of a normal distribution. Note that I used the independence of $X$ and $Y$ in third equality.

Comment: If I want to calculate p(S,T). This is equal to [Cov(S,T)]/[sqrt(Var(S)*Var(T))]?

Comment: If by $p(S,T)$ you mean correlation then yes.